# Pygame Colliderect Not Functioning

Tags: python, pygame

Problem with Pygame! Colliderect function doesn't detect when two rects collide! The rects just fall through each other, though no error message is given. Why is this and how can it be fixed? Been struggling on this same problem for days on end! Supposed problem spot is labeled with a comment. Thanks in advance!

```
#Start it up
import pygame
pygame.init()
fpsClock = pygame.time.Clock()
#surface = pygame.display.set_mode((640,480),pygame.FULLSCREEN)
surface = pygame.display.set_mode((640,480))
pygame.display.set_caption('Game Skeleton')

#Globals and Misc.
x = 10
y = 350
l = 15
w = 35
moveX=0
moveY=0
characterRect= pygame.Rect(x,y,l,w)
ground = pygame.Rect(0,385,700,385)
ledge1= pygame.Rect(310,330,20,20)
jump=0
white = (255,255,255)
black = (0,0,0)
firebrick = (178,34,34)
blockRects = [ground,ledge1]
contact = False
playOn = True
var=0

#standingLeft = pygame.image.load("images/
#standingRight = pygame.image.load("images/
#walkingRight = pygame.image.load("images/
#walkingLeft = pygame.image.load("images/
#straightJumping = pygame.image.load("images/
#rightJumping = pygame.image.load("images/
#leftJumping = pygame.image.load("images/
#inquire = pygame.image.load("images/
#climbing = pygame.image.load("images/


#Game Loop
while playOn:

    #Take user input
    for event in pygame.event.get():

        if(event.type==pygame.KEYDOWN):

            if(event.key==pygame.K_RIGHT):
                moveX=1

            if(event.key==pygame.K_LEFT):
                moveX=-1

            if(event.key==pygame.K_UP):
                moveY=-1

            if(event.key==pygame.K_DOWN):
                moveY=1

            if(event.key==pygame.K_SPACE):
                jump=1

            if(event.key==pygame.K_ESCAPE):
                playOn = False

        if(event.type==pygame.KEYUP):

            if(event.key==pygame.K_RIGHT):
                moveX=0

            if(event.key==pygame.K_LEFT):
                moveX=0

            if(event.key==pygame.K_UP):
                moveY=0

            if(event.key==pygame.K_DOWN):
                moveY=0

    #If user input said to move
    x = x + moveX
    y = y + moveY

    #Jump Code
    if(jump>0 and contact==False):
        y=y-jump - 1
        var=var+1
        if(var>45):
            jump=0
            var=0

    if(contact==False):
        y=y+1

    if(contact!=True):
        contact==False

    #These two "ifs" don't appear to be working D:
    if (ground.colliderect(characterRect)):
        y=y-1
        contact == True

    if(ledge1.colliderect(characterRect)):
        y=y-1
        contact == True

    #Renderings    
    surface.fill(white)
    pygame.draw.rect(surface,black,(x,y,l,w))
    pygame.draw.rect(surface,firebrick,(0,385,700,385))
    pygame.draw.rect(surface,firebrick,(340,350,100,5))   
    fpsClock.tick(80)
    pygame.display.flip()

pygame.quit()
```

Comment: Oh! I see what you mean...though, call me a n00b, but how do I render characterRect on each iteration? pygame.draw.characterRect doesn't work, but I'm sure that's waay off. Do I need more variables?

Comment: `y = y + moveY` is the same as `y += moveY` and `y = y - 1` is the same as `y -= 1`.

Comment: Yeah, thanks. I just feel more comfortable using the longer method because I'm used to it from this outdated class I took on Python. I should probably stop that now though...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are initializing:

```
characterRect= pygame.Rect(x,y,l,w)
```

Then you update x,y,l,w variables independently and forget about the `characterRect`, so the characterRect rect is always on the same position.

You can make the updates directly on the `characterRect` or assign the new `y` value before checking for `colliderect`.

@Justin Pearce corrections are also important, otherwise your code will not work correctly.

Also take a look at [PEP 8](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/). For a good looking python code, you should remove brackets around the `if` conditions.

Comment: To add, you would do: `characterRect.y -= 1` There's many virtual rect properties. See: http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html

Comment: Thank you soo much! I get it now!...except when I switch from the x --> characterRect.x and y--> characterRect.y I can't move. LOL I'm just happy it's not that same problem! Cheers!

Comment: Perhaps you move but you are still drawing the (x,y,l,w) rect?

Comment: You're right. Wow, thanks. But I don't know how to fix it. When I switch it all to characterRects, I get this:
AttributeError: 'pygame.Rect' object has no attribute 'l'

Comment: In the page linked by @monkey you have all the attributes, l translates to height and w to width. In the draw method you just pass the characterRect variable instead of the tuple `pygame.draw.rect(surface,black,characterRect)`

Comment: Thanks! I was wondering what was up...it works now...well sort of. The collideRect is working well with the ground, though ledge 1 is transparent. I think it's something fixable, but if you catch it easily, by all means, the more help the better. Thanks for everything!

Answer (score 2):

You have this:

```
if(contact!=True):
    contact==False

#These two "ifs" don't appear to be working D:
if (ground.colliderect(characterRect)):
    y=y-1
    contact == True

if(ledge1.colliderect(characterRect)):
    y=y-1
    contact == True
```

Should that not be?:

```
if(contact!=True):
    contact=False

#These two "ifs" don't appear to be working D:
if (ground.colliderect(characterRect)):
    y=y-1
    contact = True

if(ledge1.colliderect(characterRect)):
    y=y-1
    contact = True
```

Double equals is a *comparison* operator, not an *assignment* operator.